# How to close browser at the end of watir test suite?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, watir

Using ruby's watir to test a web app leaves the browser open at the end. Some advice online is that to make a true unit test you should open and close the browser on every test (in the teardown call), but that is slow and pointless.  Or alternatively they do something like this:

```
 def self.suite
   s = super
   def s.afterClass
     # Close browser
   end

   def s.run(*args)
     super
     afterClass
   end
   s
 end
```

but that causes the summary output to no longer display (Something like "100 tests, 100 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors" should still display).

How can I just get ruby or watir to close the browser at the end of my tests?

Comment: Which test runner are you using? Test::Unit?

Comment: Test::Unit::TestCase  As long as it works the same, it doesn't bother me.  Just trying to make what I was given work better.

Answer (score 12):

When you want to use one and only browser during your [RSpec](http://rspec.info) specs, then you can use `:suite` hooks instead of `:all` which would create and close browser within each example group:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :suite do
    $browser = Watir::Browser.new
  end

  config.after :suite do
    $browser.close if $browser
  end
end
```

However, if for some strange reason you would not want to use RSpec or any test framework yourself then you can use Ruby's [Kernel#at_exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) method:

```
# somewhere
$browser = Watir::Browser.new
at_exit { $browser.close if $browser }

# other code, whenever needed
$browser.foo
```

I'd still recommend to use a testing framework and not create your own from scratch.

Comment: @pguardiario global variable is necessary here because setting variables in `:suite` hooks in RSpec means that scope is different from all the examples/examplegroups. Also, using global variables for singleton objects (you only have one browser, right?) in places where it makes sense is not a `shit hack`. Or, how would you solve it?

Comment: I don't really have anything better. Sorry, I'm deleting that comment.

Answer (score 2):

RSpec and Cucumber both have "after all" hooks.

RSpec:

```
describe "something" do
  before(:all) do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
  end
  after(:all) do
    @browser.close
  end
end
```

Cucumber in (`env.rb`):

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new

#teh codez

at_exit do
  browser.close
end
```